# Shell Scripting - how to read text file and create a list from it by add a single digit at the end of each word

Tags: shell

So let say i have a "fruit.txt" file with a word in each line like

Apple
Banana
Chestnut

how do i read the text file and create a list in the form of

Apple0
Apple1
Apple2
...
Chestnut9

?

Comment: How are the values of the traling digits chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless which shell you write your script in, you will need to loop over the names in the file `fruit.txt` and then loop the number of times you want to append that many digits to each word in the file. Nested loops with the outer looping through the names in `fruit.txt` and the inner looping once for each digit to append. (to append `0-9` you loop `10` times with the inner loop)

Since you tagged with `[shell]` you are asking for a POSIX shell compatible solution. That can be something as simple as:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

fname="${1:-fruit.txt}"       ## set filename to read (default fruit.txt)
nvers="${2:-10}"              ## take no. of version to create with digits 

## validate file is available and non-empty or exit
[ -s "$fname" ] || {
  printf "error: %s is not found or empty.\n" "$fname" >&2
  exit 1
}

## read each line in fname
while read -r word; do
  n=0                                 ## set counter zero
  while [ "$n" -lt "$nvers" ]; do     ## loop $nvers many times
    printf "%s%d\n" "$word" "$n"      ## write word with digit
    n=$((n+1))                        ## increment counter
  done
done < "$fname"
```

(if you were using bash, you could use a C-style `for((...))` loop for the inner loop)

**Example Use/Output**

Since there a default values for each `fname` (`fruit.txt`) and `nver` (`10`), you simply need to run the script if you want the defaults, e.g.

```
$ sh append_digits.sh
Apple0
Apple1
Apple2
Apple3
...
Chestnut7
Chestnut8
Chestnut9
```

To create only 4 versions of each fruit you can simply give the necessary arguments, e.g.

```
$ sh append_digits.sh fruit.txt 4
Apple0
Apple1
Apple2
Apple3
Banana0
Banana1
Banana2
Banana3
Chestnut0
Chestnut1
Chestnut2
Chestnut3
```

---

**Using awk**

The proper tool for the job in shell is `awk` where you can simply read each line in the file looping however many times needed to append the digits you want, e.g.

```
$ awk '{ for(i=0; i<10; i++) print $1 i }' fruit.txt
Apple0
Apple1
Apple2
Apple3
...
Chestnut7
Chestnut8
Chestnut9
```

If you want to pass-in the number of versions to create you can use the `-v` option to declare an `awk` variable on the command line, e.g.

```bash
awk -v n=4 '{ for(i=0; i<n; i++) print $1 i }' fruit.txt
```

Which would output `0-3` versions of each fruit. Much easier.